# Wrote the wrong date in a reply to accept an interview, should I point it out?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, internship, email

I recently got an email offer for a phone interview for a summer internship, and when I replied I wrote something along these lines:

> I'm available during xx:xx-xx:xx this Wednesday, the 8th and xx:xx-xx:xx on this Friday, the 10th. I'm also available during xx:xx-xx:xx this Thursday, the 19th.

The problem here is that the 8th and the 10th already passed (I received their email today and replied immediately).

Should I send another reply and mention that I meant the 16th and 18th, or just not mention anything? The times I gave work both this week and last week, so I won't need to reschedule. They haven't replied to this email yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want your potential employer to have to guess what you meant. I certainly wouldn't have guessed that 8th and 10th actually means 16th and 18th, since they're not on the same days of the week.

Everyone makes mistakes, but how you rectify those mistakes (or how you don't) is what will matter to the company. ***Send another reply*** to clear things up.

Comment: Wouldn't there be issues if substantial edits are simultaneously?

Comment: I suggest we discuss about this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) instead :)